# jsonpath string filter camel-jsonpath

Tags: jsonpath

I'm would like validate JSON string to ensure that all the keypair values are valid via camel-jsonpath.

Using example from jsonpath.com.

> {
>    "firstName": "John",
>    "lastName" : "doe",
>    "age"      : 26,
>    "address"  : {
>      "streetAddress": "naist street",
>      "city"         : "Nara",
>      "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
>    },
>    "phoneNumbers": [
>      {
>        "type"  : "iPhone",
>        "number": "0123-4567-8888"
>      },
>      {
>        "type"  : "home",
>        "number": "0123-4567-8910"
>      }
>    ]
>   }

To filter phoneNumber where type="home" with this syntax it works fine.
**$.phoneNumbers[?(@.type=="home")]**

But to filter for firstName=="John" it does not work.

**$[?(@.firstName=="John")]**

Can you assist me with the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
..[?(@.firstName=='John')]